# Why should we not place block elements inside inline elements

Tags: html, validation

If I place a div element inside an anchor element, it invalidates my HTML.

What is the reason of not placing block level elements inside inline elements ?

Comment: You can get the rules from W3. As for the reasoning and history behind rules, good luck.

Comment: Because [it doesn't parse correctly in older browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091739).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I place a div element inside an anchor element, it invalidates my HTML.

[This is not true as of HTML5.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-a-element)

> What is the reason of not placing block level elements inside inline elements?

The HTML specification describes which elements may contain other elements. ["Flow content"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#flow-content-1) can often contain "Flow Content", or ["Phrasing Content"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-1), but even this is not always the case. For example, a `p` element is a block level element, but it may only contain "Phrasing Content".