# Make a div clickable but have another div appear over it

Tags: html, css

It's hard to explain without a picture, so if your willing to help, visit this page: http://www.laoistidytowns.ie/node/2

Ok, so on this photo I have the following CSS: (note this is just one picture, but i have classes for each placename)

```
.ballacolla
{
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      margin-right:40px;
      margin-bottom:46px;
}

.ballacolla a
{
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%; 
     top:0; 
     left:0; 
     text-decoration:none; /* Makes sure the link   doesn't get underlined */ 
     z-index:10; /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */ 
     background-color:white; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */ 
     opacity: 0; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */ <br>
     filter: alpha(opacity=1); /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
}

.innerbox
{
      position: absolute; 
      bottom: 0;
      width:180px;
      height:30px;
      background-color:#000;
      opacity:0.75;
      filter: alpha(opacity=40);
      padding-left:20px;
      padding-top:10px;
      z-index: +1;
}

p.boxtag
{
color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ballacolla"><a href="www.google.com" target="blank"><div class="innerbox"><p class="boxtag">Abbeyleix</p></div></a></div>
```

.ballacolla = the dic square container
.ballacolla a = allows the div to be clickable
.innerbox = dark grey box on the bottom
.boxtag = the writing in the innerbox

My problem is the innerbox (grey box) disappears if the link is working. How do I stop the innerbox from disappearing?

Comment: using jquery you can stop propagation  [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: `.innerbox` doesn't disappear. The parent anchor actually disappears because you've set `opacity: 0;` on it, taking the child elements with it. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `opacity: 0`?

Comment: My opacity is set to 0.75 on the innerbox, to make it slightly see through, it's not set to 0... it's set to 0 in the .class a fields... to make the link clickable

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, even with HTML5, you are having difficulties with the div in the link...mixing inline with block styles.

I would take a look at some of the other threads on here pertaining to that. This one points you to a good method of styling a span as a div using a special class and the `display;block` method: [div inside anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091739/html-div-in-link-problem)

you can always go for the `onclick=();` event on the div as well and eliminate the `a` tag all together.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles, it says opacity:0 for a tags. Add a class a below.

```
.field-items a{
    background:none;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I figured it out. I had to close the  tag right after the first div in my html. ie my html now looks like : `<div class="abbeyleix"><a href ="www.google.com"></a><div class="innerbox"><p class="boxtag">Abbeyleix</p></div></div>`

the reason you don't have anything between the  tag is because you actually are doing all the work in the CSS... such a simple fix, but it's working now, thank you all for your help